# Segmentation Fault Error over Writing the Twitter Stream on a Text File

Tags: c, file, stream, twitter, segmentation-fault

I have a C program that opens a stream of tweets from Twitter API. What this program aims to do is to open a stream and write the stream to a text file. This program is successful when it just prints the stream in the terminal but when I change the code to write to a file there's now a "segmentation fault" error for about 40 seconds into the execution. `size_t writefunc(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, struct string *s)` is the callback function that writes the stream to a file particularly at

```
fp=fopen("istream.txt", "a");
fprintf(fp, "%s", s->ptr);
fclose(fp);
```

Why is there a "segmentation fault" error? How should I fix this? I guess I am using the file pointer the wrong way.

==================================

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

struct string {
  char *ptr;
  size_t len;
};

void init_string(struct string *s) {
  s->len = 0;
  s->ptr = malloc(s->len+1);
  if (s->ptr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  s->ptr[0] = '\0';
}

size_t writefunc(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, struct string *s)
{
  size_t new_len = s->len + size*nmemb;
  size_t max_buffer = 10240;
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen("istream.txt", "a"); // <------------- the ERROR! Remove this.

  s->ptr = realloc(s->ptr, new_len+1);
  if (s->ptr == NULL) {

    fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  memcpy(s->ptr+s->len, ptr, size*nmemb);
  s->ptr[new_len] = '\0';
  s->len = new_len;

  if( s->len >= max_buffer )
  {
    fp=fopen("istream.txt", "a");
    fprintf(fp, "%s", s->ptr);
    fclose(fp);

    fflush( stdout );
    free(s->ptr);
    init_string( s );
  }

  return size*nmemb;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;


  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    struct string s;
    init_string(&s);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json");
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "neilmarion:password");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writefunc);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    //printf("%s\n", s.ptr);
    free(s.ptr);

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're leaking an open file every time `writefunc` is called.

Comment: What do you mean @muistooshort?

Comment: How many `fopen` calls are in `writefunc`? Do you `fclose` everything you `fopen`?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. That was a typo error. I edited the code above. @muistooshort Though nothing was solved even the extra fopen was removed from the real code. Segmentation fault still looms.

Comment: Oh! Sorry @muistooshort That was actually the error. Thank you!

Comment: Cool, I expanded the comment into an answer if you want something to accept.

Answer (score 1):

Most things looks correct in your program.

Most likely if `fp=fopen("istream.txt", "a");` fails to open the file, it could be a segfault in the consecutive line.

Try to print the string in `stderr` instead to see. If that works, than issue is indeed in `fp`.

**Other comment:**
Since you are opening the file in append mode, there is actually no point in collecting the data in the buffer and keep re-allocating the buffer. You can at once append the file.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The error was actually found. There was just an extra fp=fopen("istream.txt", "a"); in the code that is not being closed. I edited the code again for everyone to see.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you enter `writefunc` you open `istream.txt`:

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("istream.txt", "a");
```

but you never call `fclose` on the `fp`. You do have this:

```
fp=fopen("istreaam.txt", "a");
fprintf(fp, "%s", s->ptr);
fclose(fp);
```

later on but the second `fopen` means that you no longer have a reference to the what the first `fopen` returned.

Eventually, you will run out of open files and further `fopen` calls will fail. Apparently this takes about 40 seconds. So get rid of the first `fopen` and try again.